# Volley PUT StringRequest not sent

Tags: android, android-volley

I am sending a StringRequest using Volley to update a single record in mysql.The url is fine when i am sending the same request from postman i am getting result but when i send the request from android its not sent. I am not getting whats the issue.I am sendin two values that too iam sending it in url.Here is the code

```
 StringRequest req = new StringRequest(Request.Method.PUT, url,new Response.Listener<String>() {
                    @Override
                    public void onResponse(String response) {

                        resp = Integer.parseInt(response.toString());
                        hidepDialog();

                        if(resp == 1){
                            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),"Success",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                        }else{
                            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),"Failure",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                        }

                    }
                }, new Response.ErrorListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error) {

                    }
                });
```

Comment: did you add it to volley's request queue ?

Comment: yes,requestQueue.add(req);

Comment: you should check if onErrorResponse and the content of error

Comment: I am not getting any response....either +ve response or error response.